# M2 | Do enterprise version have wallet feature by default?

Tags: magento-enterprise, payment-methods, payment, amount

There is an eWallet feature offered as third party extensions for community edition of Magento 2.

For Example in this extension:

https://magento-modules-demo-demo9420020898.webkul.com/demomanagement/viewdemo/index/demoid/12/

Customer have balance in his account and can purchase by his account balance also can recharge amount any time.

Is this feature available in Magento Enterprise Edition by default like Gift Cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, This feature is available by default in Magento 2 Commerce as **Store Credit**.

Here is the official Document link:

https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.1/ee/user_guide/sales/credit-refunds.html